# Failed insert or update when add type column long text using NHibernate in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using Nhibernate 4 and FluentNhibernate 2.0.3 with db Microsoft Access 2000. I can't save the entry on the DB because i'm getting an error when I go to insert the **Note** field sending a request HTTP POST for example:

{
    "Note": "bla bla bla"
}

**NOTE:** In the database table, the column "Note" is setted as "LONG TEXT" (Not Required)

Could It be a problem of conversion of data Types?

Here's the stack trace:

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not insert: [Domain.Destinatari#1773][SQL: INSERT INTO `Destinatari` (Note, IDDestinatario) VALUES (?, ?)] ---> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Errore di sintassi nell'istruzione INSERT INTO.
   in System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   in System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   in System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
   in System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
   in System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   in System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   in NHibernate.JetDriver.JetDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   in NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand cmd)
   in NHibernate.AdoNet.NonBatchingBatcher.AddToBatch(IExpectation expectation)
   in NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id, Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, Int32 j, SqlCommandInfo sql, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
   --- Fine della traccia dello stack dell'eccezione interna ---
   in NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id, Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, Int32 j, SqlCommandInfo sql, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
   in NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id, Object[] fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
   in NHibernate.Action.EntityInsertAction.Execute()
   in NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)
   in NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list)
   in NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions()
   in NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session)
```

Below my mapping code:

```
Public Class DestinatariMap
        Inherits ClassMap(Of Destinatari)

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New
            LazyLoad()
            Id(Function(x) x.IDDestinatario).GeneratedBy().Increment()
            Map(Function(x) x.Note)
        End Sub
End Class
```

Here's my Domain code:

```
Public Class Destinatari

        Private _ID_Destinatario As Integer
        Private _Note As String

        Public Overridable Property IDDestinatario() As Integer
            Get
                Return Me._ID_Destinatario
            End Get
            Set
                Me._ID_Destinatario = Value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Overridable Property Note() As String
            Get
                Return Me._Note
            End Get
            Set
                Me._Note = Value
            End Set
        End Property
End Class
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to Insert a value to id that is an auto increment in the database?

Comment: The primary key on the database is auto increment then my request HTTP POST only contains "Note" field.

Comment: I've discovered that the word **Note** is a reserved word in DB access.
In order that it can perform the mapping of columns with reserved keywords it  needs to put ` on both sides, like this:

```
Map(Function(x) x.Note).Column("`Note`")
```

Here's link with keywords list for Access:

[Learn about Access reserved words and symbols](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2)